Properties of Nth roots and fractional powers
Context: I'm programming an arbitrary precision math library and created some weird algorithms to calculate a number raised to non-integer powers due to optimizations.
From my understanding, raising any number to a fraction is essentially finding the Nth root of that number. I've implemented Newton-Raphson method to approximate the solution, but the higher the root, the slower the convergence rate is. Because of this, I was forced to use factorization to find larger roots to optimize the speed of the code. For example $\sqrt[5]{\sqrt[2]{x}}=\sqrt[10]{x}$, where the first part takes much less time to calculate rather the latter.
Let's say I want to find $x^{.376}$, the algorithm would do $(\sqrt[10]{x}^{3})(\sqrt[10]{\sqrt[10]{x}}^{7})(\sqrt[10]{\sqrt[10]{\sqrt[10]{x}}}^{6})$.
This worked like a charm but I could not find any resources online on how this works and what properties of powers and roots are being applied here. In all honesty, I only figured this work around out because I realized that each place of the fractional exponent corresponds to a lower magnitude, and using a similar approach as the factorization. Using 10 as a baseline for the radicals, then raising it to the power of the digit in that place gave the next factor.
Furthermore, I also found that if I wanted to find $x^{.7}$, the algorithm could do $\sqrt{x}(\sqrt[5]{x})$. I have a better understanding of this because of how powers can be factorized, but I'm still a bit confused as to exactly how all this works together for Nth roots and fractional exponents as a whole.
I've looked for weeks as to why this approach works but couldn't find anything remotely explaining it, and the basic rules of powers and roots I was able to find never really alluded to it either. I really stumbled on it by chance after not being able to sleep and having a "this might work" moment, then tested it out using a calculator on a whim at 5am.
If anyone can help explain why this works, and if this is something that's known, I will be forever greatful.

It all works because $a^b \times a^c=a^{b+c}$ and $(a^b)^c=a^{b \times c}$ at least for positive $a$. So in your examples:

$\sqrt[5]{\sqrt[2]{x}} = (x^{1/2})^{1/5}=x^{1/10}=\sqrt[10]{x}$
$(\sqrt[10]{x}^{3})(\sqrt[10]{\sqrt[10]{x}}^{7})(\sqrt[10]{\sqrt[10]{\sqrt[10]{x}}}^{6})  = x^{3/10}\times x^{7/100} \times x^{6/1000} = x^{0.3}\times x^{0.07} \times x^{0.006}= x^{0.376}$
$\sqrt{x}\sqrt[5]{x}=x^{1/2}\times x^{1/5}=x^{0.5}\times x^{0.2}=x^{0.5+0.2}=x^{0.7}$

If you are finding $\sqrt[2]{x}$ much faster than other roots, then you might consider optimising your square root function, writing the exponent in binary, and just using multiple square roots.  For example $0.625$ in decimal is $0.101_2 =\frac12+\frac{1}{2^3}$ in binary and so $x^{0.625}=x^{1/2}\times x^{1/2^3}=\sqrt{x} \times \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}$.
Or you could use logarithms, with $a^b = c^{b \, \log_c(a)}$.  With pencil and paper and log-tables it would be best to use common logarithms with $c=10$.  With a computer, you might prefer natural logarithms with $c=e$ or binary logarithms with $c=2$.

Thank you for laying this out so simply. Seeing it in actual fractions and not decimal made a real difference. I didn't realize it was similar to the property of logarithms where it can turn multiplication into problems of addition in a way. I recently came across the quake 3 inverse sqrt algorithm so your answer will be excellent help in understanding how that works.
